# Trouble with plugin meme generator and input files

Tags: image, input, resize

I try to integrate a plugin
Demo here: http://makg10.github.io/jquery-meme-generator/
The js code and read.me here:

https://jsfiddle.net/t6xu4pyf/1/

```
(function($){

    var i18n = {
        topTextPlaceholder: "TEXTE HAUT",
        bottomTextPlaceholder: "TEXT BAS",
```

Server side and client, it works for me if I put directly the url of an image in my html.

If I use 
It also works except that the image does not resize to upload.
I'm very very bad with the canvas and I do not know at all if I can work on the size of the image directly in the plugin code or if I have to resize the image "before" with other function? ()

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: "meme generator"...huh. Also are you running into a specific error or just asking a broad question about how you should proceed? If you do have an error, please try to narrow down where it is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, solution was client side.
It is about the image resize before upload ... no more.
The answer already existed in many topic above. Sorry.
Anyway, here's the code:

```
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var current_file = input.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (event) {
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.src = event.target.result;

                    image.onload = function () {
                        var maxWidth = 500,
                                maxHeight = 500,
                                imageWidth = image.width,
                                imageHeight = image.height;


                        if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
                            if (imageWidth > maxWidth) {
                                imageHeight *= maxWidth / imageWidth;
                                imageWidth = maxWidth;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if (imageHeight > maxHeight) {
                                imageWidth *= maxHeight / imageHeight;
                                imageHeight = maxHeight;
                            }
                        }

                        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                        canvas.width = imageWidth;
                        canvas.height = imageHeight;
                        image.width = imageWidth;
                        image.height = imageHeight;
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

                        $('#example').attr('src', canvas.toDataURL(current_file.type));
                    }
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
                    $("#inputfiles").change(function(){
                        readURL(this);
                    });
```